# OBSOLETE - Stacktistics: Show recent popular languages, mobile platforms and web techs based on question counts

Tags: app, obsolete, python, jquery, google-app-engine

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: stacktistics web pag]

[image]

### About

You may wonder what kind of languages, mobile platforms, or web technologies are most popular these days.
stacktistics shows the popularity of programming languages, mobile platforms and web technologies based on the number of questions in a Stack Overflow site, updated on a monthly basis.
Also, stacktistics provides [basic learning resources](http://www.stacktistics.com/references/php.html) for each language such as hello world sample codes, recommended books and interesting Stack Overflow questions list.

#### License

None

#### Download

http://www.stacktistics.com/

#### Platform

Tested with Chrome, Firefox and IE8 for desktop.
Tested with iPhone and iPad browser.

### Contact

[wonil.kim@stacktistics.com](http://matil:wonil.kim@stacktistics.com)

### Code

I wrote this application by using Goolge App Engine [Python webapp framework](http://code.google.com/intl/ko-KR/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingwebapp.html) with Django template. Use [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/index.html) to show pie chart. Use [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) for mobile web page.

Comment: Great! You could also use [gRaphaël](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) for the charts - just an idea.